# Evaluate the sum $\sum_1^n{2k+1\over k(k+1)}$ in closed form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, closed-form

Evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n{2k+1\over k(k+1)}$$ in closed form. You are allowed to have the harmonic number $$H_n = \sum_1^nk^{-1}$$ in your closed–form formula.

I am having trouble with this problem. As of now, I have tried the perturbation method of splitting the last term on one side and the first term on the other. However, that method does not seem to work and I am stuck. It would be much appreciated if you can help me work through this problem.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle \frac{2k+1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Another way: $\frac{2k+1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{2}{k+1}+\frac1{k(k+1)}$ and the later is telescoping.

Comment: After I have separated the original term into 1/k+1 and 1/k, how would I go about to figure out the closed form of 1/k+1?

Comment: @Bow: $\sum_{k=a}^b \frac{1}{k+1} = \sum_{k=a+1}^{b+1}\frac{1}{k}$. Then, express it in terms of $H_{a+1}$, $H_{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Galc127's hint:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{2 k + 1}{k (k + 1)}
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \left(\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k + 1}\right) \\
  &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k} + \sum_{1 \le k \le n + 1} \frac{1}{k} - 1 \\
  &= 2 \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{n + 1} - 1 \\
  &= 2 H_n + \frac{1}{n + 1} - 1
\end{align}$

In general, if you have a rational function to sum it is often useful to split into partial fractions.

Comment: @ClementC., fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Or $H_{n+1}+H_n-1$.